# SharePoint 2013 Connection Issues in Windows from External Network

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content, reverse-proxy

I am connecting to SharePoint 2013 from an external network.

Everything on the site seems to work fine, except when something happens which opens up a windows frame inside of the browser (i.e. adding content to the site).  It appears as though this popup is attempting to access the server via the local address (sourceserver.domain.local) instead of the puplic address (portal.domain.com).

What is going on?

[image: Connection Error while adding content to site]

This is what I get on a different computer:
[image]

p.s. here are my AAMs
[image]

Comment: This sounds like an alternate access mapping issue. Can you post your AAMs or check them to ensure they are correct?

Comment: @RobertKaucher - See above

Comment: William, those look good. What's the dialog for? I noticed the image has 'Dialog' in the upper left. This isn't something custom, is it?

Comment: Nope - nothing custom at all - this is basically a brand new install of SharePoint -